# Understanding Effective Annual Interest Rate concept

Tags: interest, compound-interest

I am trying to understand the effective interest rate concept with an example. All I know about it is the following formula:

```
EAR = (1+r/n)^n -1 , where

n = number of periods
r = stated interest rate
```

So in my example we have the following:

```
PV = 1000
Rate annually is 10%
```

FV in two years would be

```
FV = PV(1+r)^n
   = 1000(1+0.10)^2
   = 1210
```

Now if we change the problem to

```
What will be the FV if interest rate is compounded quarterly?
```

If the rate is applied quarterly, then should I use the same formula but with n = 8 compounding periods for two years?

Comment: n=8 is correct, and r=.10/4 or .025, i.e. 2.5% per period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a nominal rate, `i = 10%` compounded quarterly, the quarterly rate can be found in two ways.

1. Directly by `q = i/4 = 2.5%`

or 2. via the effective annual rate* :-

```
ear = (1 + i/4)^4 - 1 = 0.103813 = 10.3813 %
q = (1 + ear)^(1/4) - 1 = 0.025 = 2.5 %
```

* ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation

The amount accumulated in two years can be calculated using the quarterly rate or the EAR :-

1. `1000 (1 + q)^8 = 1218.4`
2. `1000 (1 + ear)^2 = 1218.4`

If, on the other hand, the effective annual rate is 10%

```
ear = 0.1
fv = 1000 (1 + ear)^2 = 1210
```

then the quarterly rate will be

```
q = (1 + ear)^(1/4) - 1 = 0.02411 = 2.411 %

fv = 1000 (1 + q)^8 = 1210
```

and the nominal rate compounded quarterly `i = 4 * q = 0.09645 = 9.645 %`